# Como puedo mejorar la eficiencia de este algoritmo de números primos en Java?

Tags: java, eficiencia

estoy implementando un algoritmo en Java que halla la cantidad de números primos hasta un numero grande, generalmente un numero entre 10 a 15 cifras, por lo que estoy manejando la clase `BigInteger`. El problema es que se demora bastante en terminar este algoritmo. El algoritmo se define bajo el siguiente código:

```
private long encontrarPrimos(BigInteger n) {
    long inicio = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(n.toString());
    BigInteger i = BigInteger.ONE;
    while (i.compareTo(n) <= 0) {
        if (evaluarNumero(i)) {
            cant++;
        }
        i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE);
    }
    //System.out.println("Cantidad de numeros: " + cant);
    long fin = System.nanoTime();
    long finalTime = fin - inicio;
    //System.out.println("Tiempo: " + finalTime);
    return finalTime;
}
```

En la anterior función recorro con un ciclo los números desde 1 hasta el numero grande propuesto (Que puede tener 10 a 15 cifras), en cada iteracion le paso el numero i para que calcula si este numero es primo o no.

```
private boolean evaluarNumero(BigInteger number) {

    if (!number.isProbablePrime(5)) {
        return false;
    }


    BigInteger two = new BigInteger("2");
    if (!two.equals(number) && BigInteger.ZERO.equals(number.mod(two))) {
        return false;
    }


    for (BigInteger i = new BigInteger("3"); i.multiply(i).compareTo(number) < 1; i = i.add(two)) { 
        if (BigInteger.ZERO.equals(number.mod(i)))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

El método anterior define si el numero en `BigInteger` es numero primo o no.

Mi pregunta es como puedo optimizar este algoritmo, sin alterar su funcionamiento principal, pero que, se demore menos en su ejecucion.
Gracias.

Comment: Hola, por lo que he entendido el problema es contar la cantidad de primos hasta un numero n optimizando el algoritmo que has propuesto. Sin cambiarlo no se me ocurre pero a lo mejor te interesa el metodo de [Meissel-Lehmer](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1985-44-170/S0025-5718-1985-0777285-5/S0025-5718-1985-0777285-5.pdf) para contar primos. En la pagina 23 hay una tabla con los tiempos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veo que el algoritmo ha venido de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32035942/255257) de la versión en Inglés de StackOverflow, y diría que es bastante bueno si quieres evaluar números de manera general. Es decir, si de pronto necesitas evaluar si el número `X` es primo o no.

Pero dado que tu problema es distinto, pues vas evaluando los números en orden, veo la oportunidad de optimizarlo de dos maneras, con lo cual queda garantizado una mejora de al menos 5X si evalúas números entre 1 y 100,000 (ya explicaré por qué), y mejorará aún más si evalúas muchos más números.

Y es que si vas evaluando los números en orden, realmente no hace falta *probar* si un número es primo dividiéndolo entre todos los números impares anteriores a él (que es como el algoritmo funciona). En realidad, hay que probar dividirlo solo entre los números primos anteriores a él.

Para ello, puedes mantener una lista con todos los números primos anteriores y cambiar la implementación de la rutina `evaluarNumero`, a algo como:

```
private boolean evaluarNumero(BigInteger numero, List<BigInteger> primosAnteriores) {

    BigInteger primo;
    for (primo : primosAnteriores) { 
        if (BigInteger.ZERO.equals(number.mod(primo))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Fuera, ya solo te toca declarar una lista de `BigInteger` e ir añadiendo a ella los números primos. Debes tener cuidado de no añadir el 1, que técnicamente por definición es primo, pero que daría al traste con nuestra implementación. Es decir, inicia con el número dos:

```
BigInteger i = new BigInteger("2");
while (i.compareTo(n) <= 0) {
    if (evaluarNumero(i), listaPrimos) {
        listaPrimos.add(i);
    }
    i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE);
}
```

La segunda *optimización* que sugiero hacer es no llamar a `isProbablePrime()` –la rutina de arriba ya no la llama– basado en la mera suposición que probablemente resulte más optimo evaluar como lo he hecho y por tanto la llamada a esta rutina resulte en una pérdida de tiempo, pues para los que estima que si son primos, de todas maneras hay que pasar por la evaluación completa. Sugiero que hagas una implementación con la llamada y otra sin ella, y que te quedes con la que en la vida real, resulte más optima.

Finalmente, he dicho al inicio que estimo que al menos será 5X más rápido que la implementación anterior. Esto es basado en que, del 1 al 104729 hay solo 10K números primos.

En tu implementación anterior, para el número 104729, se tenía que probar dividir con 52364 números impares anteriores a este, mientras que ahora solo habría que dividir dentro de 9999 números, lo que nos arroja un factor de 5.23X.

Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias bro, aun así estoy que sigo mejorando este algoritmo, ya que tengo que contar números primos dado un valor, por ejemplo, para este numero, el cual se genera automáticamente: 779950758830178

Comment: Si ese es el caso, otra posible y grande optimización es que almacenes un diccionario con los números primos que tu programa encuentra cada vez. Entonces, cuando tienes un nuevo número por probar, pruebas contra lo que ya está almacenado y vas haciendo crecer ese diccionario de números primos. Esto reduciría significativamente el tiempo que toma probar si un nuevo número es primo o no.

Comment: Es decir, que cada vez que encuentre un número primo nuevo lo agregue al diccionario, y si ya existe lo omite, según entiendo

Comment: Cada vez que encuentre un número primo nuevo lo agregas al diccionario, y para todos los números que ya existen en el diccionario, no hace falta ir probando, simplemente haces un lookup para ver si existe ese número y sabes directamente si es primo o no. Con una lista ordenada, esto se convertiría en O(logn)